# Fixar inputs gerados a partir de botão no form

Tags: javascript

Estou com o seguinte problema: Criei um botão que gera dois campos input dentro de um form, o problema é que quando a página da refresh os campos gerados somem. Queria saber como faço para que eles uma vez gerados permanecessem no form até serem excluídos via botão de exclusão(Ainda a ser desenvolvido ^^")

Seguem os códigos:

```js
var line = 1;

function addInput(divName) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    
    newdiv.innerHTML  = '['+line +']';
    newdiv.innerHTML += '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label>Quando alguém disser:</label><input type="text" name="leitura'+line +'_1" id="leitura'+line +'_1"><br></div><div class="col-md-6"><label>O bot deve responder:</label><input type="text" name="resposta'+line +'_2" id="resposta'+line +'_2"><br></div></div><br>';
      
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    line++;
}

addInput('lines');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 py-3">
            <form id="form">
                <button type="button" onclick="addInput('lines')">+ Adicionar Resposta</button>
                <br><br>
                <div id="lines"></div>  
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas você quer que fique pra sempre? Nesse caso, teria que guardar no servidor. Mas para esse tipo de armazenamento, pode usar o localStorage ou sessionStorage, depende da forma como você quer. Você tá armazenando onde? 
 http://sbesc.lisha.ufsc.br/sbesc2014/dl234

Comment: @RodrigoRocha estou desenvolvendo para que os inputs sejam lidos e usados por um bot para responder a dadas perguntas, então esses campos tem que ficar até serem excluídos. Pensei em gerar junto com a row um botão que seria responsável por deletar a row quando ela não tivesse mais serventia, mas para agora preciso que depois de gerados os campos permaneçam depois de um f5 por exemplo. E caso seja fechada a aba, quando for aberta novamente o que foi gerado e não excluido permanecesse. Não sei se estou conseguindo me explicar direito, perdão

Comment: Então. Você tem que armazenar isso em algum lugar, entende? Por exemplo, em um banco de dados ou arquivo no servidor. No lado cliente você resolve salvando na sessão ou em armazenamento local, porém será apenas na sessão atual ou na máquina.

Comment: Entendi o que você quis dizer. Consegue me dar um exemplo de como começar?

Comment: Você usa alguma linguagem back-end? PHP, C#...

Comment: Nada de back-end no código ainda, mas estou acostumado a usar PHP caso a pergunta tenha sido essa

Comment: Então. Você pode armazenar no banco de dados. Toda vez que adicionasse guardaria no banco de dados. Ao excluir, excluiria.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode salvar os campos gerados no localStorage para recupera-los após o refresh

```
function addInput(divName) {
     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

     newdiv.innerHTML  = '['+line +']';
     newdiv.innerHTML += '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label>Quando alguém disser:</label><input type="text" name="leitura'+line +'_1" id="leitura'+line +'_1"><br></div><div class="col-md-6"><label>O bot deve responder:</label><input type="text" name="resposta'+line +'_2" id="resposta'+line +'_2"><br></div></div><br>';
     document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

     localStorage.setItem(divName, document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML); //<- add no localStorage
     line++;
}


addInput('lines');
var inputs = localStorage.getItem('lines'); // <- recuperando dados no localStorage
```

após isso precisa pensar em uma logica para ficar atualizando o localStorage durante as ações da sua aplicação